# Correct way to implement jQuery with require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd

I am using the current stable release of both require.js and jQuery and I am currently including jQuery like this

```
requirejs.config({
paths: {
    'jQuery': 'vendor/jquery',
}
});

require(['jQuery'], function(jQuery) {
    log(jQuery); // working
});
```

What I don't get is that I don't really need to explicitly give back jQuery, as this will still work (also in other modules):

```
require(['jQuery'], function( // nothing here ) {
    log(jQuery); // working
});
```

Now I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing it, also because using the $ dollar sign for reference to jQuery doesn't work!

Comment: If you are in the latest version on jQuery which supports AMD, you can follow this link: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/jquery-using-only-what-you-need/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The key points as I see it:

1. jQuery when used with RequireJS registers itself as named module 'jquery' (all lower case). In your example you are trying to use it as 'jQuery', which confuses things a bit since this is also the name of a global function that it registers when loaded (see point #2).
2. By default, jQuery registers itself using the global functions "$" and "jQuery", even when used with AMD/RequireJS. If you want to turn off this behavior you have to call noConflict function.
3. You can wrap your RequireJS reference to jQuery in a noConflict call, as shown in the example below. As far as I can tell, this is the recommended approach when you don't have other modules which need the global $ or jQuery:

   ```
   requirejs.config({
       paths: {
           'jquery': 'vendor/jquery',
       }
   });

   define('jquery-private', ['jquery'], function (jq) {
       return jq.noConflict( true );
   });

   require(['jquery-private'], function(jq) {
       console.log(jq);      // working
       console.log($);       // undefined
       console.log(jQuery);  // undefined
   });
   ```

See also [my answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574500/stop-global-jquery-with-plugin-in-requirejs/15577738#15577738) regarding how to map other modules to use the private (noConflict) version.

For more background, see these lines from the jQuery source code which are the cause of everything I described above:

```
    // Expose jQuery to the global object
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;

    // Expose jQuery as an AMD module, but only for AMD loaders that
    // understand the issues with loading multiple versions of jQuery
    // in a page that all might call define(). The loader will indicate
    // they have special allowances for multiple jQuery versions by
    // specifying define.amd.jQuery = true. Register as a named module,
    // since jQuery can be concatenated with other files that may use define,
    // but not use a proper concatenation script that understands anonymous
    // AMD modules. A named AMD is safest and most robust way to register.
    // Lowercase jquery is used because AMD module names are derived from
    // file names, and jQuery is normally delivered in a lowercase file name.
    // Do this after creating the global so that if an AMD module wants to call
    // noConflict to hide this version of jQuery, it will work.
    if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd && define.amd.jQuery ) {
        define( "jquery", [], function () { return jQuery; } );
    }
```

**UPDATE:** the [Use with jQuery section of the RequireJS site](http://www.requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html) has been updated to reflect the above info. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17615594/using-private-jquery-with-requirejs-issue-after-optimisation/17625765#17625765) for step-by-step including optimizer. Just want to emphasize again that this noConflict approach only works if **all** your plugins are AMD compatible.

Comment: I did this and most of my scripts work, but in some, $.fn is undefined even though $ seems ok... Any idea why?