# Setting up folders for require.js

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I am trying to set up folders for require.js and I am just having errors.

Here is my folder structure:

```
Web folder
--default.html
--[Scripts]
----main.js
----require-cfg.js
----require.js
----[lib]
------jquery1-9.1.js
```

my require-cfg.js

```
var require = ({
    baseUrl: 'Scripts',
    paths: {
        jquery: '/lib/jquery-1.9.1'
    }
});
```

In my main.js:

```
require(["require-cfg"], function (core) {

});
```

in my default.html

```
 <script src="Scripts/require-cfg.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/require.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/main.js"></script>
```

I have a function in the main.js that uses jquery syntax.  When I run the web app, I am getting the error"

> JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

can anyone direct me on what I am doing wrong??

THanks!!

-- I figured out that By default, jQuery registers itself using the global functions "$" and "jQuery", even when used with AMD/RequireJS. If you want to turn off this behavior you have to call noConflict function:[Correct way to implement jQuery with require.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613577/correct-way-to-implement-jquery-with-require-js)

adding the below worked:

```
define('jquery-private', ['jquery'], function (jq) {
    return jq.noConflict( true );
});
```

Comment: Should 'require(["require-cfg"]' be 'require(["require-cfg.js"]'? Just a guess.

Comment: according to this:  http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html, I don't need the .js when requiring it.

Comment: Maybe try switching <script src="Scripts/require-cfg.js"></script> and <script src="Scripts/require.js"></script> around? Just another guess.

Comment: Thanks, had tried that too.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with require.js. Does it use jQuery? If so, perhaps there is some conflict with the jQuery version it is using and the one you're including. Also, it usually tells you what line of code in which file your error is occuring in your js console. Does it say that?

Comment: my JS console has no error. It only errors when a jquery selector ($) is used.

Comment: You're not supposed to use separate <script> tags for each file, `data-main` should be the only entry point (and this is one of the reasons for using RequireJS). Follow the examples from the documentation you linked above step by step, you can easily build up on them.

Comment: When you say "adding the below worked" do you mean your problem is fully resolved now?