# Using JQuery inside modules with Require.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, requirejs, amd

I want to use jQuery with require.js and I got some problem
I need to use jQuery inside module1 & 2

The require.js is working well but not able to load jquery

This is the **index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Basic example of requireJS integration</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <p>Check console and js files</p>
</div>
<script data-main="js/main" src="js/vendor/require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the **main.js**

```
// Load modules and use them

    requirejs.config({
        path: {
            'jquery': '../js/vendor/jquery-3.1.1.min',
        }
    });
require(['module1', 'module2'], function (module1, module2) {
    debugger;
    console.log(module2.testMod1() + " " + module2.testMod2());
});
```

This is **module1**

```
define([], function () {
    return {
        doSomething: function () {
            return 'something';
        }
    };

});
```

This is **module2**

```
define(['module1', jquery], function (module1, $) {
    return {
        testMod1: function () {
            debugger;
            console.log("jquery obj" + $);
            return module1.doSomething();
        },
        testMod2: function () {
            return "something 2"
        }

    };

});
```

I read this but not able to make it work...what am I doing wrong here ?
[Correct way to implement jQuery with require.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613577/correct-way-to-implement-jquery-with-require-js)

**update:**
still after changing like Michael Sacket answer, having same issue
this is my project structure

[image]

**Now the error is:**

```
require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Script error for "jquery", needed by: module2
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:168)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1735)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to implement jQuery with require.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613577/correct-way-to-implement-jquery-with-require-js)

Comment: @SkinnyJ  - No if you read my question you can see that I try this and still not working ...

Comment: @SkinnyJ - you give the link that I already put in the question...

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems.  First, your RequireJS configuration should be outside of the `require()` function.

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': '../js/vendor/jquery-3.1.1.min',
    }
});
require(['module1', 'module2'], function (module1, module2) {
    console.log(module2.testMod1() + " " + module2.testMod2());
});
```

Your function is trying to load module1 and module2 before it does any configuration.

Secondly, you should rename your jQuery module to be all lowercase so that it doesn't conflict with the global `jQuery`.

```
define(['module1', 'jquery'], function (module1, $) {
    return {
        testMod1: function () {
            debugger;
            console.log("jquery obj" + $);
            return module1.doSomething();
        },
        testMod2: function () {
            return "something 2"
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: thanks , change it like you said and now the error is :require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Script error for "jquery", needed by: module2
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:168)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1735)

Comment: please see my update I added there the proj structure ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change the `path` in the require.config to `paths`